# how to use incomplete Cholesky factorization in Eigen

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, eigen

I need to use the incomplete Cholesky factorization from the C++ Eigen library.
I followed the [documentation of Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1IncompleteCholesky.html#ac39c75ff7ca5d2db9a9f03b937e12601). Specifically, I have a matrix A and I want to obtain the zero fill in incomplete lower triangle Cholesky factor L. In matlab, I can simply do ichol(A). It seems to be tricky to do it in C++ with Eigen. Based on my understanding of the documentation, I should use it as follows. However, the result I got is always 
different from what Matlab command ichol() returns.

```
Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> A = cov_matrix.sparseView();
Eigen::IncompleteCholesky<double, Eigen::Lower, Eigen::NaturalOrdering<int>> ichol(A);
std::cout << ichol.info() << std::endl;
Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> L = ichol.matrixL();
Eigen::VectorXd S = ichol.scalingS();
Eigen::MatrixXd D = S.asDiagonal();
Eigen::PermutationMatrix<Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> P = ichol.permutationP();
sparse_L_chol = D.inverse() * L;
```

Comment: What do you really want/expect? Recall that incomplete Cholesky is not uniquely defined, it depends on parameters such as allowed fill-in, reordering, etc...

Comment: @ggael What I really expect is the zero fill-in ichol. Now I realized that Eigen implements the threshold based ichol, which is different with the zero fill-in version. Is there a zero fill-in version of ichol in Eigen?

Comment: Actually it does zero-fill-in too, but with a shift, otherwise the factorization is not always possible. BTW, it is not necessary to apply the permutation in the case of `NaturalOrdering` (it means use the identity permutation).

Comment: @ggael How to use the zero fill-in version? Could you please specify?

Comment: It does it by default, the number of non zeros in the lower triangular part of A and L should be the same, but the locations won't.

Comment: @ggael I see. But that's not the version I want. What I need is the zero-fill-in version where zeros of A are also zeros of L.